# Keyboard not working in GRUB menu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows

I recently dual-booted my windows 8.1 laptop with ubuntu 14.04. The GRUB was working fine once I set it up, but suddenly the keyboard seems disabled in GRUB and only boots into ubuntu now. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13343/115216) ?

Comment: Can it be a BIOS problem? Is it an USB or PS2 keyboard? Is the BIOS set up to auto-detect that type?